# Allow tinymce class attribute when div added

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to add div with class to tinymce but it keep being stripped off, first i could not add div - so i added this line

```
        forced_root_block : 'div',
```

so now when i do

```
<div class="foo">foo</div>
```

it turns into

```
<div>foo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting `forced_root_block` to a `<div>`?  Not saying its wrong just curious why you want that as a root block instead of a `<p>` - the editor's default behavior.

That is the root cause of this issue here ... if you don't use `forced_root_block` this should work and not remove the class.

Comment: Michael - thanks, i used 'forced' because i couldn't add div... it was stripped for some reason.... i also checked the valid_elements and it's set to allow all valid_elements : '*[*]', - so i really can't figure it out  why i can't add div and assign them classes

Comment: @RoyBarOn a "vanilla" TinyMCE instance would keep your `<div>` as is - so you have something else in your configuration that is causing this to happen.  I would review the remainder of your configuration to figure out what is causing it to get rid of the `<div>` if you don't use `forced_root_block`.